# How do I sign commits in Git? Warning - options not active

Tags: git, gnupg

I am using Windows to sign my commits and push.
I have tried using `gpg` command on `cmd` after installing `git-bash`.

```
gpg --list-secret-keys --keyid-format LONG
```

But seems like I am doing something wrong, the warning that I am getting is  -

> Warning - options in 'C/Users/.../gpg.conf' are not yet active during
>   this run

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well that just seems to be a warning when you start of using `gpg`.
Try this :

```
gpg --gen-key
```

and then follow the steps selecting a key of your choice. Once you have completed these steps, try again the same command

```
gpg --list-secret-keys --keyid-format LONG
```

***Source*** - [Github Documentation](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-a-new-gpg-key/)